# How to make widgets stack on top of each other using QScrollArea with Vertical layout in PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I'm super new to PyQt5 and trying to design a notification panel where the most recent notification should be placed on top rather than the bottom. For notification I'm using QLabel widget and for notification panel, I'm using a QScrollArea with vertical layout and vertical policy set to Fixed since otherwise it places the label in the center rather than top.

So, the problem is, it is placing my new labels on the bottom when I want to place new ones on the top.
I tried to mess with the geometry function, by creating a list to append each new notification label and then traverse the list from highest index to lowest, changing each label's y-axis value accordingly.
Here's the code for that:

```
        if len(self.alert_labels_list) > 0:
            loop_ran = 0
            for l_index in range(len(self.alert_labels_list), 0, -1):
                temp_label = self.alert_labels_list[l_index-1]
                new_ay = self.label_height + 31    # 31 is the y pos for first label while label height is self defined variable that contains the set height which in this case is 80. 
                self.label_height = new_ay
                temp_label.setGeometry(11, new_ay, 430, 80)


        self.x_label.setGeometry(11, 31, 430, 80) # x_label is the new label being added.

        self.label_height = 80

        [...]
        # code which sets the label
        [...]

        self.alert_labels_list.append(self.x_label)
```

The idea here is that starting from the highest index we'll encounter the most recent labels (alerts) and by adding the (fixed, defined) label height to the y position of prev label we'll make all labels appear in a recent order. I hope it makes sense.
Anyway this logic above still doesn't work, maybe because the layout is not letting me customize the position of new widgets being added to it or something?

If you can guide me how can tackle this issue, I'd be more than grateful to you! Thanks!

Comment: Why not just use a `QVBoxLayout` for your scroll area viewport? It makes adding and removing labels a lot easier.

Comment: I think that's what I'm already doing; applying QVBoxLayout to my QScrollArea. Like you said it does make things a lot easier but I need it to allow me to stack the most recent ones on top rather than bottom.

Comment: @abaid your code doesn't show any usage of layouts (which, by the way, automatically invalidates trying to set a geometry, since that's prerogative of the layout itself). In any case, if you're using a box layout and want to insert widgets at the "beginning", use `layout.insertWidget(0, widget)`.

Comment: @musicamante You're a LIFESAVER, SIR. And I'm honestly so so sorry for being an idiot and not making my question more clearer, I thought not including code where I applied VBoxLayout and other setup stuff, would be fine if I just explain in theory because that seemed perfectly fine to me when the problem was actually in that code portion.

THANK YOU SOOOO MUCH to you and again I deeply apologize, I'll make sure not to repeat such idiocracy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Huge thanks to @musicamante, his comment contains the answer.
I'll just quote him here, "*...if you're using a box layout and want to insert widgets at the "beginning", use* `layout.insertWidget(0, widget)`"